# YouTube Api V3: Access not configured

Tags: api, youtube

The api key I used was deleted by the Person who gave it to me, no big deal, I can generate my own one.

I created the Project, activated the Access to the YouTube api, created my key and tryed to use it in my Project.

At first I got the message, that the key would be bad or was non existing. After a few minutes, the key seemed to be registered, but now i get a different error message:

```
   domain: 'usageLimits',
   reason: 'accessNotConfigured',
   message: 'Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 'my Project id' before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project='my Project id' then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.',
```

When I open the given URL, i just get the overview, where even is mentioned, that the API is activated: 
Aktivierungsstatus
Aktiviert

I tried to delete my key, deactivate the API again, reactivate it, and create a new key. And I added my Domain to the trusted Domains.
Tried different restrictions for the calling and the APIs, and even removed all restrictions.

What could cause the problem?

Answer (score 22):

I more or less (didn't) solve the Problem.

After waiting for some days Overall, and recreating keys, reactivating the api and much more, i gave up today.
Looked through many tutorials and blog Posts and just did a step by step guide on how to use the api for a WordPress YouTube Plugin.

So, i created a new Project (almost identical Name) on the same Google account, activated the api, created the api key, and on the first try, without waiting or anything, it worked.

3 Steps:
- Create a new Project
- Activate the api
- Create the api key

I dont know why this does not work on my first Project, as i did the exact identical steps.

Comment: I had the same experience.  Only creating a new project and key fixed the issue.

Comment: Same for me. Had to make a new project entirely

Comment: for how long? The issue seems to occur repeatedly

Comment: Same experience, thanks to this post. I just created a new project and a new key to resolve "access" error.

Comment: Confirmed from here.  I noticed that the old project name had an underscore in it, and this is now not allowed in project names.

Comment: that is so annoying... creating a new project and using that key worked. My key was working for like 3 years and stopped working recently.