# Youtube API v3 shows “Access Not Configured”

Tags: javascript, youtube-data-api

A month ago I created a Youtube visualization using the Youtube API, it was doing great until last week the API just stopped responding.

Tried to;

- Disable/enable the API (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27491718/447988)
- Added referrers (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29783456/447988)
- Created a new key

One thing that I haven't tried is creating a new project as I don't have permission to do it. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54456853/447988)

Looking at the report everything seems fine https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX3ev.jpg

The code is simple;

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics&chart=mostPopular&regionCode=JP&maxResults=50&key=xxx
```

The error is the following;

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project xxx before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxx then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxx"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project xxx before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxx then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
 }
}
```

Comment: As reported here on stackoverflow, the creation of a new project seems to be the only solution to this issue.

Comment: Does Google have tech support?

Comment: Yes, it [has](https://issuetracker.google.com/)! Unfortunate is that, since about two months now, the staff stopped taking into consideration any issue [raised](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc).