# How to resolve "Access Not Configured" for Youtube Data API

Tags: java, google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I'm having trouble setting up even the most basic access to the Youtube Data API v3. Part of the problem is inconsistencies between testing on the Java Quickstart page for the API and using the generated code in an actual Java program.

I can follow these instructions https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/java
and have the API work on the https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw%22%7D
webpage for listing a channels contents using a channel ID.

The problem is when I copy out the code to my gradle project in the appropriate location, I get a 403 error. Code being used is below, and my json client_secrets file is in my src/main/resources folder as expected.

```java
public class ApiExample {
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRETS= "client_secrets.json";
    private static final Collection<String> SCOPES =
        Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly");

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "API code samples";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /**
     * Create an authorized Credential object.
     *
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize(final NetHttpTransport httpTransport) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = ApiExample.class.getResourceAsStream(CLIENT_SECRETS);
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
          GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .build();
        Credential credential =
            new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized API client service.
     *
     * @return an authorized API client service
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
     */
    public static YouTube getService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        final NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Credential credential = authorize(httpTransport);
        return new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
    }

    /**
     * Call function to create API service object. Define and
     * execute API request. Print API response.
     *
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, GoogleJsonResponseException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, GoogleJsonResponseException {
        YouTube youtubeService = getService();
        // Define and execute the API request
        YouTube.Channels.List request = youtubeService.channels()
            .list("snippet,contentDetails,statistics");
        ChannelListResponse response = request.setId("UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw").execute();
        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

I would expect the same HTTP 200 response that I get from the API Examples page with the appropriate JSON listed. The problem when I run the actual Java application is a 403 error.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 113360591925 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=113360591925 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "reason" : "accessNotConfigured",
    "extendedHelp" : "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=113360591925"
  } ],
  "message" : "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 113360591925 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=113360591925 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
}
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1067)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
        at ApiExample.main(ApiExample.java:82)
```

I have the appropriate scopes set up, but I have not gone through the verification steps because this is an internal app which will touch Youtube at most three times a week (and on average once). The scopes I have setup are shown here https://www.dropbox.com/s/74owbu9589v4xrl/Capture.PNG?dl=0 with the client secret having been made today with the YouTube Data API enabled.

Do I need to be verified, I was under the assumption that I didn't given the working examples. I don't have a domain or privacy policy to provide. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After even more research and some further testing, I found a question answer here on StackOverflow that led me to create a new project.

Using just the scope I needed for upload, this worked. I have no idea why, and nobody else seems to either. Here's the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54456853/2503583

Granted I didn't do the API key step, I made my OAuth credentials instead because that's what I needed.